# What is this \u001b[9... syntax of choosing what color text appears on console, and how can I add more colors?

Tags: node.js, colors, console, windows-console

I was messing around with [debug](http://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/node.js) and [colors.js](http://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/master/colors.js) to get more colors than the limited 4-6 colors but I'm stuck at figuring out this coloring syntax

```
args[0] = ' \u001b[9' + c + 'm' + name + ' '
  + '\u001b[3' + c + 'm\u001b[90m'
  + args[0] + '\u001b[3' + c + 'm'
  + ' +' + exports.humanize(ms) + '\u001b[0m';
```

```
'blue' : ['\x1B[34m', '\x1B[39m'],
'cyan' : ['\x1B[36m', '\x1B[39m'],
'green' : ['\x1B[32m', '\x1B[39m'],
'magenta' : ['\x1B[35m', '\x1B[39m'],
'red' : ['\x1B[31m', '\x1B[39m'],
'yellow' : ['\x1B[33m', '\x1B[39m'],
```

I know windows console allows more colors than just those six, as `color /?` shows

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

How do I go about understanding this syntax and adding the extra colors that windows has to offer?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/208150/phpunit-windows-command-box-nice-colors

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are [ANSI terminal escape codes](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).  Specifically, they're "select graphic rendition" (SGR) escape codes, which consist of:

- the "command sequence introducer", consisting of the characters `\x1B` (ESC) and `[`,
- one or more numeric commands, separated by semicolons, and
- the letter `m`, ending the code and indicating that this is an SGR code.

There are many possible numeric commands (and many other escape codes besides SGR), but the most relevant ones are:

- 30–37: set text color to one of the colors 0 to 7,
- 40–47: set background color to one of the colors 0 to 7,
- 39: reset text color to default,
- 49: reset background color to default,
- 1: make text bold / bright (this is the standard way to access the bright color variants),
- 22: turn off bold / bright effect, and
- 0: reset all text properties (color, background, brightness, etc.) to their default values.

Thus, for example, one could select bright purple text on a green background (eww!) with the code `\x1B[35;1;42m`.